# VBA - Cells.Find doesn't work with values taken from array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've got a problem with `Cells.Find` function. Mainly, I have an array with *n* rows and 2 columns, in which I have stored some values (I use `Variant` data type as it's universal one and I want my code to work as for now, not optimize it). Then I want to find a value from this array within a range. My code looks kind of like this:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant

last_row = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
x = last_row - 1
y = last_row - 1
ReDim arr(x,y)
For i = 0 To x
    arr(i,0) = ws.Cells(i + 2, 10).Value
    arr(i,1) = ws.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value
Next
```

And now, if I want to find and a value stored in `arr(0,0)` in `ws.Range("B2:B100")` I cannot do it like this:

```
ws.Range("B2:B100").Find(arr(0,0)).Select
```

because it shows

> Error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set.

What I have to do is something like that:

```
ws.Range("X1").Value = arr(0,0)
ws.Range("B2:B100").Find(ws.Range("X1").Value).Select
```

Then it works. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: You declare an `N x N` array, only fill the first column, and when filling, you overwrite `ws.Cells(i + 2, 10).Value` with `ws.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value`, so you end up having only `ws.Cells(i + 2, 11).Value` in the array. And there is something else after the `Find().`, is there?

Comment: Use `Set  fnd = ws.Range("B2:B100").Find(arr(0,0))`

Comment: Then `fnd` will save the range where your value is found

Comment: @GSerg yeah, I made a mistakes while rewriting the code, sorry about that. There shouldn't be any overwiriting and .Select after (however I didn't include it as it doesn't really matter, there is no stored value whatsoever...). Now it's ok in the main question.

Comment: @Mikku still doesn't work, sorry

Comment: @TheEditingify ..did you try the below ans ?

Comment: Yeah, nothing changed, still the same error :D

Comment: If you have to check against all values in your array in a cell (and I think that's what you are trying to do.. not sure though), I would use `Filter` as you can pass your array to `Filter`

Comment: @TheEditingify What does `? arr(0,0) = ws.Range("X1").Value` give?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realised what was the problem - data I had was formatted as a time and the problem was that the formatting of time didn't match between spreadsheet and vba. Mainly, in vba you convert number into visible h:mm:ss (e.g. 1:12:13), while in vba, using Format(x, "h:mm:ss") you always get hh:mm:ss (e.g. 01:12:13). And this was the problem why it showed error 91. It just couldn't find the value, even though it existed in the searched area. Thank you for answers guys :)

Answer (score -1):

It gives you an error because the find did not find anything. try this:

```
Set fnd = ws.Range("B2:B100").Find(arr(0, 1))
If Not fnd Is Nothing Then fnd.Select
```

Comment: I know why it shows an error. But it should have found the value, because this value appears in the range. And given solution also shows an error... :(